# How to explode jquery tabs into the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a page that looks something like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                           |
| +----------------------------+ +--------+ |
| |main                        | |sidebar | |
| |                            | |+------+| |
| |                            | ||jquery|| |
| |                            | || tabs || |
| |                            | |+------+| |
| |                            | |        | |
| |                            | |        | |
| +----------------------------+ +--------+ |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

in which a have jQuery tabs elements with 4 tabs.  I would like to have one button that would show all 4 tabs at the same time on the whole page with a close option to get it back as it was before.  Something like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                           |
| +------------------+ +------------------+ |
| | tab 1            | | tab 2            | |
| |                  | |                  | |
| +------------------+ +------------------+ |
|                                           |
| +------------------+ +------------------+ |
| | tab 3            | | tab 4            | |
| |                  | |                  | |
| +------------------+ +------------------+ |
|                                     close |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Any idea on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar recently. Assuming that your tabs are DIV elements, have the button call code doing something along these lines

```
function expand(){
  $('div.tab').each(function(){ 
    $(this).show(); //Make sure all our tabs are visible
    $(this).removeClass('tab'); //Remove any sizing etc. previously applied to the tab by your stylesheet
    $(this).addClass('expandedtab'); //Apply class which sets proper size, floats left etc.
  }); 
}
```

Then create a `collapse` method which reverts the operations performed by `expand` and have your Close-button call it. If you find that `collapse` needs to know something about the state of affairs before `expand` was called (like which tab was active), have `expand` use the [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method to store this information for later retrieval by `collapse`.

NOTE: If you prefer, instead of removing the 'tab' class and adding the 'expandedtab' class, you can just apply/override specific styles making `expand` add a style-attribute to the tab DIV and have `collapse` remove the attribute.